# Encoding problem with nordic characters

Tags: character-encoding, ascii

I'm trying to send HL7 messages to a receiver. The receiver now says they got question marks instead of '`ä`' and '`ö`'. What should I do?

Right now I do it about like this:

I initialize System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient and then

```
Dim data(payload.Length) As Byte
Dim stream As System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream = _tcpClient.GetStream()
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload).CopyTo(data, 1)
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
```

Payload is my message of type string including characters like '`ä`' and '`ö`'.

I'm using Visual Studio 2003 and framework 1.1.

Comment: The ASCII character set does not contain such characters.

Comment: Also: Using payload.Length as the length of the Byte-Array assumes that a String of _n_ characters will always result in a byte-Array of _n_ bytes. That's not true for UTF-8.

Comment: And: I'm pretty sure you don't need to the CopyTo at all, just use the result of GetBytes()

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about HL7, but basically your problem is that you're using ASCII.

What encoding does HL7 allow? If it lets you use UTF-8, that's probably the easiest fix - just change your use of `Encoding.ASCII` to `Encoding.UTF8`.